# How can the NEST kernel be completely reset?

Tags: python, nest-simulator

Is there a way to completely reset the NEST kernel to its original state as it was when you first `import nest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use [`nest.ResetKernel()`](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/pynest_tutorial/part_2_populations_of_neurons.html?highlight=resetkernel#resetting-simulations)